# clear selection on datatable after closing dialog with Escape

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:commandButton` that calls a `p:dialog` with a `p:dataTable` inside. The user should be able to select one or more rows (saving every element in a list inside the bean) and click a "Save" button to save that data on the database. My problem is when I select some rows from this dataTable and then press the ESC key, the dialog closes like it should but when I open that dialog again, the values that were selected but not saved are still selected. I know i can make closeOnEscape="false" and make a "cancel" button and set the list in the bean to null, but I was wondering if there is a way to 'clean' that datatable after closing the dialog with ESC. Im working with Primefaces 4.0

My dialog looks something like this:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="coolName" modal="true"
        appendTo="@(body)" resizable="true" closeOnEscape="true"
        closable="false" position="center" showEffect="clip"
        hideEffect="clip" header="really cool dialog" width="1000">

        <h:form id="form">
            <p:growl sticky ="true" showDetail="true" />

                <p:tab title="List of Elements" id="tabOne">        

                    <p:dataTable id="tblOfElements" var="listElements"
                        paginator="true" rows="5" rowKey="#{listElements[0]}"
                        paginatorPosition="bottom" rowIndexVar="index"
                        paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}
                             {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} "
                        currentPageReportTemplate="{currentPage} de {totalPages}"
                        emptyMessage="this list is empty"
                        selection="#{cBean.mBean.listOfSelection}"
                        value="#{cBean.mBean.listElements}"
                        style="text-align:center">

                        <f:facet name="header">  
                            List of Elements
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:4%;text-align:center"/>
                        <p:column headerText="N°" style="width: 4%">
                            #{index + 1}                        
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Name" style="width: 50%">
                            <h:outputText value="#{listElements[1]}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Date" style="width: 12%">
                            <h:outputText value="#{listElements[3]}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                    <br />
                    <p:commandButton value="Save" style="float: right;"
                        actionListener="#{cBean.saveElements}"
                        onclick="PF('coolName').hide()" />

                    <br />
                    <br />
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
        </h:form>

    </p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `<p:resetInput>` on your button click action that opens the dialog. So even if the values that are selected in your dialog prevails when you press escape button, every time you click and open your dialog, your selections can be cleared.

ResetInput is used to clear the cached values from state so that components retrieve their values from the backing bean model instead

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Moks: Can you upvote my answer if it worked for you?